# How do I determine the maximum number of excel sheets possible to create in a C# program?

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I know that the only limit on excel sheets is system resources, but I was wondering if there was some way I could figure out that number in C#.

Comment: It all depends on the data. This question does not have an answer.  If we are talking about x86 application its around 4GB of memory usage.  If we are talking about x64 application it can use most of the system's memory.  I do believe you can even force .NET around the 4GB limitation but only by a small amount at the cost of overall system performance.

Comment: Have you considered just trying?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx) Raymond says:

> The first answer is "If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong." Programs shouldn't be creating anywhere near ten thousands window manager objects in the first place.

And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx) he says:

> But the real question that is raised whenever somebody asks, "What's the maximum number of threads that a process can create?" is "Why are you creating so many threads that this even becomes an issue?"

Having that said, no, you can't figure a number that is limited by system resources.
Instead you must go forward and add another sheet. When there are no more resources, the `.Add` call will fail.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the Excel sheet, of the data in them, free system ressources and version of Excel and Operating System. It is definitely no deterministic value. If you really think you have to do it, use the try/catch pattern. Simply keep creating excel sheets until you catch an exception, but I wouldn't recommend this.

I don't think you really need more than one instance of one and the same Excel sheet.
we could help more if you tell us more details.